# Order id in order confirmation page Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am trying to get the order id in order confirmation. I am using cashondelivery module and I searched on the .php file but i don't know how to declare it. Any ideas?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
{$smarty.get.id_order}
```

Regards

Comment: Please do not answer low quality questions.  Though your code snippet may be one of numerous ideas that fall under "Any ideas", the question itself does not conform to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

In the file "cashondelivery.php" you should edit or override the function "hookPaymentReturn" like that:

```
public function hookPaymentReturn($params){
    if (!$this->active)
        return ;
    $this->smarty->assign(array(
        'id_order' => $params['objOrder']->id
    ));
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'confirmation.tpl');
}
```

Now you should be able to use the {$id_order} variable in your confirmation.tpl

Comment: It works adding smarrty in .php, it just have to be declare as global: global $smarty; thank you

Comment: Yes, you're right, i forgot the "global $smarty;"...
Please accept my answer if my comment helped you :).